# Looking for a silverlight 3rd Party DataGrid & Coverflow control

Tags: silverlight

I have been tinkering a while with the free opensource flow control (http://silverlightcoverflow.codeplex.com) and with the Datagrid in the Toolkit.

Both are now showing some serious bugs that are quite frustrating. I might be better off just buying a third party control, since Microsoft hasn't updated the Toolkit since over a year now. And the opensource Coverflow control has also been left to die.

What are your experiences with Silverlight controls and are there any recommendations?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Guys, this question was asked a long time ago. I can't even delete it, because it has an accepted answer. You can keep downvoting it, but what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik makes both a Datagrid and CoverFlow control and is known to have excellent VS integration, support, and pretty good looking controls.  They have demos available on their website:

http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/

ComponentArt also makes Silverlight controls (including a datagrid) but does not have a CoverFlow control and is not as well known/respected as Telerik.

http://silverlight.componentart.com/

Comment: The coverflow is beautiful. GridView is alright.  The price is quite high with $799.  I need only two of the controls. Do you think there is a way to purchase less controls for less money?

Comment: Yes the price is pretty steep if you are a single developer.  However, I would suggest emailing Telerik at sales@telerik.com and they may be able to arrange a better deal for you.  In the meantime, there is a free trial.